# How to get the value inserted in an AutoCompleteTextField (javafx, gluon)?

Tags: database, javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I'm using scene builder to create the interface of my application. The problem is that I would like to have text fields where the values entered by the user are stored in a database (and shown later on in my auto completion field). I've tried to use the built in AutoCompleteTextField but it seems that I can only get the value "selected" by the user. However, I want the user to be able to insert values that are not available in the autocompletion list, and when he enters that value, I want to store it in my database. 
If this can't be done using scene builder, is there any other way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that you have to implement this feature, for every enter key event on any TextInputControl , try injectif some king of handler that inserts the current value into a database table, then you should consume this table for any autocompletion ( may be using an observable list is wise , feed this observable list to all your autocomplete fields using a facade, this observable list may be instanciated in a class a read from the dba, add a callback so when data added you refetch or update the observable ) this is an idea one betwene a lot